# Discover or query for service interfaces on service fabric service

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric

I'm implementing a utility to backup services in service fabric applications. The goal is to automate our backup process for SF applications we implement. Services in the application that support backing up with the utility will implement an interface, something like `IMyBackupInterface`.

Enumerating stateful services in the application is pretty easy but I don't see any way to identify which services implement a particular interface.

At the moment I am just creating a service proxy for this interface and attempting to call the methods. Services that don't support the interface throw an exception like `NotImplementedException` or `ArgumentException` or `KeyNotFoundException` depending on SF SDK version.

Is there some better way to discover interfaces on services?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, maybe you can have the services that support your backup interface register themselves with a central service (e.g. the Service that schedules the backups) or inside the [PropertyManager](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/blob/dd8a9e2ea278a93a427274797264e36b360c16c1/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/Helpers/BrokerServiceLocator.cs) that holds some cluster wide available properties.

Comment: I can't find much more info about how to the PropertyManager. What is the lifetime of a property, do you know?

Comment: In my experience it's persistent in the cluster. Documentation could be better, I agree.

Comment: I have reached out to support, fyi: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67b6aac2-2fbf-4c33-853a-f564a1783160/documentation-of-the-fabricclient-propertymanager?forum=AzureServiceFabric

Comment: To summarize the accepted response from the msdn post @PeterBons linked: `PropertyManager` is part of the Naming subsystem, and is therefore critical for cluster function. Because of this, the SF product team discouraged using `PropertyManager` for arbitrary cluster configuration except in limited cases where data is small and infrequently accessed. The product team favored using a stateful service to store cluster configuration instead.